# Library not found installing RSRuby on OS X 10.7.4

Tags: ruby, r, rubygems

I'm trying to get RSRuby installed on my Mac. After calling:

```
sudo gem install rsruby
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot find the R library, aborting.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-R-dir
    --with-R-include
    --without-R-include=${R-dir}/include
    --with-R-lib
    --without-R-lib=${R-dir}/lib
    --with-Rlib
    --without-Rlib
```

I'm working on Mac OS X 10.7.4 and I installed R through the .pkg provided.

Any idea?

Comment: Instead of appending your answer to the question why don't you just provide an actual answer below?

Comment: @Dason I wasn't really sure that was the behaviour convention here, I'm somehow new to this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone in the same situation just do as follows:

```
$ R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
$ gem install rsruby -- --with-R-dir=$R_HOME
```

Comment: If R was installed using Homebrew then look for the same Resources folder in /usr/local/Cellar/r ... For me it was /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Resources

Comment: For me, it was `/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.1_2/lib/R` .

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem as I had not yet installed R on my mac(Yosemite). I did it using

```
$ brew tap homebrew/science 
$ brew install gcc
$ brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
$ brew install r
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running OS X 10.9.4 and this worked for me.

```
export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
gem install rsruby -- --with-R-dir=$R_HOME --with-R-include=$R_HOME/include --with-R-lib=$R_HOME/lib
```