# difficulty installing rsruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r

I tried to install the rsruby gem when I ran my bundler, but I hit a wall and got the following error:

> ERROR: Cannot find the R header, aborting.
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers

I tried the solution found on [installing RSRuby in Ubuntu 10.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091247/installing-rsruby-in-ubuntu-10-04)

but got this error in stead:

> gem install rsruby-0.5.1.1.gem -- --with-R-dir=/usr/lib/R
>   --with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include  ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rsruby-0.5.1.1.gem' (>= 0) in any repository

I am quite new at all of this, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ (Guessing an Ubuntu user and if so, follow the _second_ answer to that question and use the 'dev' version.)

Comment: Seems like R isn't properly installed. Have you installed it and checked as suggested here: https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby ?

Comment: Yes R is correctly installed.Running R --version R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)...

Comment: You shouldn't include gem's version, just try `gem install rsruby -- --with...`

Comment: Did you install `r-base-dev`? Try this: `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev && gem install rsruby`

Comment: Yes those were installed too. Yevgeniy's answer fixed the issue. Thanks.