# RSRuby cannot find R.h

Tags: ruby, r, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install RSRuby with Ruby v. 2.2.0 and R v. 3.0.2

When I try to install RSRuby, it throws the error:

```
ERROR: Cannot find the R header, aborting.
```

R.h is located in:

```
/usr/share/R/include/R.h
```

I've tried quite a few things, including the suggestions specified [here](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091247/installing-rsruby-in-ubuntu-10-04) and [here](http://owowthathurts.blogspot.com/2013/11/ruby-2-and-rsruby-installcompile-error.html).

In particular:

```
gem install rsruby -- --with-R-dir=$R_HOME/lib --with-R-include=$R_HOME/include
```

fails with the same error, although $R_HOME appears to be set correctly:

```
>> echo $R_HOME
/usr/lib/R
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Edit: OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: There is an inconsistency between your `R_home` and where R.h seems to be located. With `R_HOME` in `/usr/lib/R`, R.h should be located in `/usr/lib/R/include`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. R was installed with sudo apt-get install r-base-dev, which put it there. Was that incorrect?

Comment: For example, find where are located `libR.so` and `R.h`. If they are located in `/usr/share/R/lib` and `/usr/share/R/include`, respectively, then you probably should set `R_HOME` as `/usr/share/R`.

Comment: Unfortunately, libR.so is located in /usr/lib whereas R.h is located in /usr/share/R/include/R.h

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Rsruby with this command :

```
gem install rsruby -- --with-R-dir=$R_HOME --with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include/
```

If this is working and if after that ruby cannot compile the c parts of the gem, try this :

```
gem install rsruby -- --with-R-dir=$R_HOME --with-R-include=/usr/share/R/include/ --with_cflags="-fPIC -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing"
```

It is the only command that install rsruby for me.

Tested and working on debian wheesy, ubuntu 14.x & 15.x & 16.x.